# rspec NameError for postgresql_version

Tags: postgresql, rspec, version, nameerror

I don't understand why I am seeing this error when my rails application is not using postgres. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
c:\>rspec my_spec.rb

An error occurred in an after hook
  NameError: undefined local variable or method `postgresql_version' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x41284c8>
  occurred at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.1.1/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:123:in `db_version'

F
```

Comment: Turns out this was the issue: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/issues/224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, the current recommended approach is to use a version rule of "<1.1.0"

https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/issues/224